# What is the dimension of the intersection of two m-dimensional hyperplanes?

Tags: linear-algebra

I read on the stack exchange that when there is a proper intersection of a hyperplane and an affine space of dimension m, the intersection has dimension m-1. So let's say we have two hyperplanes, each of dimension m. Is it correct to say that a proper intersection of the two hyperplanes has dimension m-1? And is that proper intersection of these hyperplanes itself a hyperplane in m-space?

I am asking because I'm trying to generalize from numbers of certain types of arrangements of two or three dimensional figures to find the numbers of similar arrangements in higher dimensions. In geometry, the proper intersection of two one-dimensional lines is a zero-dimensional point. The proper intersection of two two-dimensional planes is a one-dimensional line. So is it correct to say that the intersection of two m-dimensional hyperplanes is an (m-1)-dimensional hyperplane?

Comment: We have two sets:
$$S_1=\{(x,y,z,w,v)\in\mathbb{R}^5|3v+4w+5x+2y−7z=8\};\\
S_2=\{(x,y,z,w,v)\in\mathbb{R}^5|2v+7w−3x+4y+7z=6\}.$$
Thus, we can build new sets using the following set
operations: union, intersection, set difference, etc. However, it seems to me that you defined a new set operation. Could you define precisely what do you mean by "I add the equations"?

Comment: Perhaps, Joe, if you looked at the equations $5x+2y-7z=8$, $-3x+4y+7z=6$, and their "sum", $2x+6y=14$, where you can more easily visualize what's going on since we're in three dimensions, perhaps the answers to your questions will become clear to you.

Comment: The possible answers depend very much on the dimension of the ambient space in which the hyperplanes exist. When you say "hyperplane of dimension $m$", does that imply that the ambient space has dimension $m+1$?

Comment: Yes, assume the ambient space of a hyperplane of dimension m has dimension m+1.

Comment: Wow, Joe, you completely rewrote the question, now some of the comments seem out of place.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is: do not take into account the dimensions, but the codimensions, i.e. difference between the ambient space dimension and the subspace dimension.

Then, when the subspaces are in general position (i.e. except on particular cases), codimensions add.

An hyperplane has codimension $1$, hence the intersection of two hyperplanes has codimension $2$. In your example where ambient space has dimension $m+1$ and subspaces have dimension $m$, the intersection of two subspaces has dimension $m+1-2=m-1$.

This comes from the fact that codimension is the number of equations of the subspace.

If the codimension equals the ambient space dimension, intersection is a point (dimension $0$). If the codimension is greater than the ambient space dimension, the intersection is void in the most frequent case; as an example: two lines in $\mathbb R^3$.

(Exceptions happen when the space generated by the orthogonal subspaces is not of maximal dimension, i.e. the equations are not independent. But you did not talk about that in the OP, so let's not complicate things :-).